# Easy way to convert HTML (WTForm) to static HTML email?

Tags: html, forms, email, flask, wtforms

I have a simple Flask/WTForm/Jinja2 pricing calculation app - consisting of simple form (table) of values (decimal, integer and pick values) and calc button, and a flash message for the calculated price.

A requirement is to be able to email the form with entered values and calculated result out when user hits a send button. I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to do this.

As I already generate the rendered form HTML (including price) to return from the POST route callback in Flask, I figured I could just grab this rendered output and email out as well when needed. So I have:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@auth.login_required
def price_calc():
  form = PriceForm(request.form)
  calc_output = ""

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate():
      # Calc the price and show it 
      calc_output = ....

      # If user hit 'Send' submit button
      if request.form['submit'] == 'send':
        send_outputs = True

  # Generate the rendered form    
  render_result = render_template('app.html', calc_output = calc_output, form=form)

  if send_outputs:
    # TODO: Need to convert this to fixed 'snapshot' HTML for email use
    generate_email(user, render_result)


  return render_result
```

This works and the values etc all show up but the HTML email is (of course) a full 'active' copy of the form. By this I mean I can modify values, change drop downs etc when I receive the email.

I'd like to convert this into a static snapshot (readonly) chunk of HTML with the values locked to state when captured. Is there any easy way to do this? I guess I could parse all the HTML elements and make them readonly somehow?

Alternatively there might be a way to make HTML forms sent in emails fixed (readonly)?

(I also need to strip some text and the submit buttons out but I'm guessing this will be trivial with some regex / Beautiful Soup parsing)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of stripping out text/buttons from the rendered web page is overkill and very brittle. If the web page layout changed you'd probably have to re-write your parsing/regex code. Also, the "rules" for email html markup are very different from normal web page html (e.g. inlining css, hacks for various email clients).

There is an easier way of achieving this; have separate Jinja templates for your email (html and plain text versions) and pass in the submitted form's data along with your calculated data to the render_template method when using these templates.

Simple example (using Flask-Mail):

```
def TestForm(FlaskForm):

    name = StringField(u'User Name')
    age = IntegerField(u'Age')


def generate_email(user, email_data)

    _email_html = render_template('email.html', data=email_data)
    _email_plain = render_template('email.txt', data=email_data)

    msg = Message(
        "Hello",
        sender="from@example.com",
        recipients=["to@example.com"]
    )

    msg.body = _email_plain
    msg.html = _email_html

    mail.send(msg)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@auth.login_required
def price_calc():

    #### blah blah

    # Generate the rendered form
    render_result = render_template('app.html', calc_output = calc_output, form=form)

    if send_outputs:
        # get the data that is needed for the email templates
        _email_data = {
            'name': form.name.data,
            'age': form.age.data,
            'output': calc_output 
        }
        generate_email(user, _email_data)


    return render_result
```

email.html:

```
<h1>Dear {{data.name}}, </h1>

<p>Age: {{data.age}} </p>

<p>Calculated Value: {{data.output.foo}}</p>
<p>Calculated Value: {{data.output.bar}}</p>

<p>Regards, Rickety365.</p>
```

email.txt:

```
Dear {{data.name}}

Age: {{data.age}}

Calculated Value: {{data.output.foo}}
Calculated Value: {{data.output.bar}}

Regards, Rickety365.
```

Comment: Thanks. Agree your suggestion creating separate templates is a better way to do it. For now I found I could pass an email flag to the web template and mark most things as readonly (which solved my initial problem). Doesn't work for <select> however.